# Uno Platform - Android NumberPicker doesn't render properly until you interact with the picker

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, uno-platform

I'm trying to use Android's Native NumberPicker in an Uno Platform app. What happens is that the Selected value of the picker is left-aligned until I interact with or tap the picker and then the item becomes centered.

This is the code

```
     <android:Grid x:Name="Picker">
          <widget:NumberPicker
               MinValue="1"
               MaxValue="100"
               Value="45"/>
     </android:Grid>
```

and this is the result

[image]

As soon as I tap or scroll the picker it renders properly

[image]

**Additional info:**

- I'm using Uno.UI 2.1.37
- TargetFrameworkVersion v9.0

**What I tried:**

- Programmatically tapping the picker
- Setting DescendantFocusability to DescendantFocusability.BlockDescendants
- If I create a separate Activity (and call StartActivity from MainActivity) which has the NumberPicker then the picker renders correctly on first load. Here's the code

```
[Activity(Label = "NumberPickerActivity")]
public class NumberPickerActivity : Activity
   {
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
           base.OnCreate(bundle);
           var picker = new NumberPicker(this)
           {
               MinValue = 1,
               MaxValue = 100,
               Value = 45,
               WrapSelectorWheel = false
           };
           picker.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(500, 350);
           var layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
           layout.AddChild(picker);
           SetContentView(layout);
       }
   }
```

and here's the result

[image]

so it definitely seems like the issue is only when rendering the native control within a UWP control.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a layout issue. Can you try setting a size (Width/Height) to the Grid that is around the picker ?

Comment: @JeromeLaban Setting the size didn't fix the issue.